# Cannot swap divs from top to bottom. Otherwise works

Tags: javascript

I haven't been able to make this code work. From bottom to top, it seems to work perfectly fine - that is, I drag a div element and then drop it on top of another, and it does what it is intended to do. However, when I try to swap an element with another below it, no swap occurs, and that's what's been baffling me most. Could you please shed some light on why it's not working?

```js
let thing1 = document.getElementById("thing1");
let thing2 = document.getElementById("thing2");
let thing3 = document.getElementById("thing3");

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("id", ev.target.id);
    console.log(ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();

    var thing = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("id"));
 
    var thingParent = thing.parentElement;
    
    var tgt = ev.currentTarget;
    console.log(thing)
    console.log(tgt)

    thingParent.replaceChild(thing, tgt);
    thingParent.appendChild(tgt);
    
}

thing1.addEventListener("drop", drop);
thing2.addEventListener("drop", drop);
thing3.addEventListener("drop", drop);

thing1.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);
thing2.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);
thing3.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);

thing1.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);
thing2.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);
thing3.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);
```

```css
.thing {

  width: 100%;
  height: ;
  background: red;

}

.drag {
  
 background: red;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: center;

}

#thing1 {
  background: yellow;
}

#thing2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="thing">
  <div id="thing1" class="drag" draggable="true">1</div>
  <div id ="thing2" class="drag" draggable="true">2</div>
  <div id ="thing3" class="drag" draggable="true">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always appending the `div` to be replaced at the bottom of the page, which means you can never actually replace the `div` at the bottom. I added timeouts to your code to show you what is happening [here](https://repl.it/repls/AmazingHeartyOolanguage). (Note that I added a `removeChild` call, but this happens automatically before the operation `replaceChild`, so I just made it explicit to enhance your ability to visualize what is happening.)

The solution isn't simple, because whether the choice to insert *before* or *after* an element is going to depend on whether you are coming from below or above. One easy solution is swap the two elements out for each other. This can be done by cloning one, as shown below:

```
function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();

    var thing = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("id"));

    var tgt = ev.currentTarget;

    if (thing && tgt) {
      var thingParent = thing.parentElement;
      var newTgt = tgt.cloneNode(true);
      addListeners(newTgt);
      thingParent.replaceChild(newTgt, thing)
      thingParent.replaceChild(thing, tgt);
    }

}

function addListeners(el) {
  el.addEventListener("drop", drop);
  el.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);
  el.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);
}
```

Even if you decide you actually want a different behavior, knowing how to swap two elements should give you the tools to get whatever behavior you want.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to work when there are other divs in between. Any suggestion? Thanks for answering!

Comment: You're right. My old solution was too simplistic. I gave it another shot though.